# jquery modal window

Tags: jquery-ui

In an .aspx page, I have a div with a asp:textbox and asp:linkbutton with visibility set to false. I have a link in the page that would open a modal window and show the content of the div. when the asp:linkbutton is clicked on the serverside code textbox value is not set.

```
<a href="#" id="OpenModal">Click here</a>
<div id="ShowModal" visible="false">
<asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server" width="200"></asp:textbox>
<asp:linkbutton id="btnCreate" runat="server" text="Save" onclick="btnCreate_OnClick"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#ShowModal').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, height: 200, width: 400, modal: true
        });
        $('a#OpenModal').click(function() {
            $('#ShowModal').dialog({ modal: true });
            $('#ShowModal').dialog('open');
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the server-side event handler the text of the textbox is "".
Could anyone help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question for future reference.

```
    $("#ShowModal").dialog({
        height: 200, width: 400,
        modal: true,
        width: 433,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $('#ShowModal').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        }
    });
```